# C++ - Efficient way to change endianness of arbitrary string

Tags: c++, string, endianness

I want to change the endianness of arbitrary C++ string (`std::string`)

Ex : `01234567` change to `32107654`. I do this

```
char *bswap32(const char *src) 
{
    char *dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(src));
    int idx = 0;
    while (idx < strlen(src)) {
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            dest[i + idx] = src[idx + 3 - i];
        }
        idx += 4;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

And call like this

```
char *swapped = bswap32("01234567");
std::cout << swapped << std::endl;
```

But I'm not sure, is it the efficient way in C++ .....

**Updated** with use of `std::string`

```
std::string Sbswap32(const std::string src) 
{
    std::string dest (src.length(), ' ');
    size_t idx = 0;
    while (idx < src.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            dest.insert(i + idx, 1, src[idx + 3 - i]);
        }
        idx += 4;
    }
    return dest;
}

std::string sTest = "01234567";
std::string Sswapped = Sbswap32(sTest _8);
std::cout << Sswapped << std::endl;
```

Comment: Have you looked into `std::rotate`?

Comment: But strings don't have endianness? What you're trying to do has no meaning.

Comment: Why `malloc` instead of using decent C++ features?

Comment: @FredLarson Not to mention the UB that comes by using an unterminated C-style string.

Comment: @FredLarson Though I agree the design decision is questionable, strictly speaking there isn't a memory leak. It's still possible to `free` the allocation with `char *swapped`.

Comment: @FredLarson I start in C ++

Comment: What should happen if `strlen(src) % 8 != 0`? Also `strlen` should be called only once, and certainly not in a loop.

Comment: What's a string's endianness?

Comment: You state in your first sentence that you want to use `std::string` but your code is not using it.

Comment: If I were to make a guess, I'd say that this is an academic exercise OP was given that tries to somehow "simulate" byte ordering modification using string manipulation functions. OP can confirm that this might be simply a 4-tuple-wise reversal that is not actually related to endianness.

Comment: If you're just starting in C++, then please [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and learn it properly.

Comment: @NathanOliver you mean `std::reverse`

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, yes I did ;) good catch

Comment: @ALL Upadte with with use of `std::string`